# Dynamic control type in InstantiateIn() method of ITemplate based on properties of DataItem. Is there a way?

Tags: data-binding, gridview, asp.net-3.5

I have a simple `GridView`; something like this for a regular `Item` or `AlternatingItem` row:

```
+----+-------------+----------+
| ID | Description | Value    |
+====+=============+==========+
| 01 | Some text   | 0.082    |
+----+-------------+----------+
| 02 | Some text   | Yes      |
+----+-------------+----------+
| 02 | Some text   | 9/4/2009 |
+----+-------------+----------+
```

When a user chooses to Edit a row in the `GridView`, only the "Value" column should become editable. I want to somehow, based on a property of that row's `DataItem`, render a control (in my case, either a regular `TextBox` for decimal values, a `DropDownList` for the "Yes/No" booleans, or something more complex like a `TextBox` with some Calendar control) for editing that value based on its type.

So for starters, the object that contains the above information has a `DataFormat` property on it that has the value I need to determine which control to render.  I have a started a custom `ITemplate` control.  Its `InstantiateIn()` method looks like so:

```
Public Sub InstantiateIn(ByVal container As Control) Implements ITemplate.InstantiateIn
    Select Case Me.ItemType
        Case UDFTemplate.Value
            Dim valueLabel As New Label()
            AddHandler valueLabel.DataBinding, AddressOf ControlDataBinding
            container.Controls.Add(valueLabel)

        Case UDFTemplate.EditValue
            ' I don't always want a text box... I want to decide what to create here.
            Dim editBox As New TextBox()
            editBox.Columns = 15
            AddHandler editBox.DataBinding, AddressOf ControlDataBinding
            container.Controls.Add(editBox)
    End Select
End Sub
```

My goal is to somehow get to the `DataItem` property of the `GridViewRow` I'm in to decide what type of control to build in the `InstantiateIn()` method.

Is this possible?  I thought I'd do it this way to keep it clean and all in one place.

If you've read this far, thank you! Just a little more: Would there be a way to alter the `ItemTemplate` for a single cell, say, by overriding the `RowDataBound` event handler of the `GridView`?  I've scoured the Internets for a long time looking for an example of somebody doing this but I can't find a single one.  I've seen some examples where they are finding the `GridViewRow` through the `container` variable by casting its `Parent` or `NamingContainer` properties to a `GridViewRow`, but both are always `Nothing` when I've looked at them.

I've also tried something like assigning a CSS class to the `DataControlFieldCell`s in the `GridView`'s `RowCreated` event, and then finding it in the `InstantiateIn` method and using it to figure out which control to render.  The problem with that is that it only works for the initial creation of the rows, but as soon as the user hits the "Edit" and it rebinds, the `DataItem`s on the rows are back to `Nothing`s and the `RowCreated` throws a bunch of 'Object not set...' bologna.

So... any ideas out there anyone?

Comment: Interesting question...I'm guessing it is not possible this way because the controls need to be in place before the data can be bound to them; since the controls are created first, there is no way to tell the data type beforehand.  Could you build a custom user control that either shows/hides a text box, checkbox, etc based on the bound data type, or adds the correct control to the control collection in CreateChildControls/Render instead?

Comment: Ok, so for a temporary (?) workaround, in the InstantiateIn() method for the UDFTemplate.EditValue type, I add all of the possible controls I'll need to edit the value with an ID and their Visible properties set to False.  In the GridView's RowDataBound event handler, I set the one visible that I need to see to make the edit.  To me, this is an ugly hack, but it could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with the route explained in my comment in response to pjabbott.