# Can Datagrid column contain diffterent type of control in different row

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

In Wpf, Can I create a datagrid which different row contain different type of control in same column?

For easiest case: datagrid with 5 cols, 2 rows, don't care about 4 first cols, in 5th col:

- 1st row: it's a textbox
- 2nd row: it's a combobox.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a DataGridTemplateColumn combined with a few triggers to achieve this functionality.

This is a demo application that binds a DataGrid to a list of (string) Control Types.  The first column just displays the control type string, and the second column acts on the same information to present the corresponding Control.  You might be able to make the xaml a bit more concise, but this is the jist of it:

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridWithMultipleTypesPerColumn.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ControlTypes}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Control Type" Binding="{Binding}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Actual Control">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl>
                            <ContentControl.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="TextBox">
                                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <TextBox Text="Default Text"/>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="CheckBox">
                                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <CheckBox Content="Check Box"/>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="Button">
                                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <Button Content="Button"/>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </ContentControl.Style>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Code-behind and View Model:

```
namespace DataGridWithMultipleTypesPerColumn
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> ControlTypes
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        public ViewModel()
        {
            ControlTypes = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Button", "TextBox", "CheckBox" };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank guy, I can do it now. I found an instruction which is quite easy to understand: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mag201104DataPoints. I do not try your instruction yet, but it seems make sense.

Comment: How would this work with data binding to the control we are dynamically selecting?

Comment: How can we make binding work in this case? For example, you have this: <TextBox Text="Default Text"/>, but how do we bind Text property to something? The problem is this TextBox doesn't have DataContext and doesn't see parent's datacontext.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. You need to create a template for your column.

See this: [WPF DataGrid different edit controls within a single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277874/wpf-datagrid-different-edit-controls-within-a-single-column)