# WPF DataGrid with different UserControl in each Cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatemplateselector, celltemplate

I hava a data model which looks like this:

```
public class Model
{
    public string DisplayAs {get;set;} // TextBox, CheckBox, ComboBox
    public string Value {get;set;}
    public string DisplayName {get;set;} // Row1, Row2, ...
}
```

Now I want to display these models in a Datagrid which shall look like this:
[image: Datagrid with a other control in each cell]

How could I achieve this? Please provide some example code.
I tried the whole day with different kind of DataTemplateSelectors but I just can't get it working

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question like what you bind to Combobox,TextBox and CheckBox?

Comment: The Value property of the model. For correct DataTypes there will be a IValueConverter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277874/wpf-datagrid-different-edit-controls-within-a-single-column
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639292/can-datagrid-column-contain-diffterent-type-of-control-in-different-row/14641742#14641742

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your selector selects a template for the cells in the second column based on their `DisplayAs` value. You have to add the templates to your `DataGrid.Resources`. Then in the second column, you assign the `CellTemplateSelector`

```
public class DynamicDataTemplateSelector: DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate
        SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

        if (element != null && item != null && item is Task)
        {
            Model model = item as Model;

            return element.FindResource(model.DisplayAs + "Template");
        }

        return null;
    }
}

<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TextBoxTemplate">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxTemplate">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTemplate">
            <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="RowName">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{DisplayName}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Data" 
             CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource DynamicDataTemplateSelector}"/>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGrid/>
```

Comment: Thank you Lee! That was what I was searching for. Seems not as complicated after a night of sleep. As I want my model to represent several of this "control columns" I used a ContentPresenter in the DatagridTemplateColumn for which I apply the TemplateSelector. So i can bind a certain property to the ContentPresenter