# How to create different type of cells in same column in DataGrid - WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to create a dataGrind in WPF c# with different type of cells in same column to take user input.

My DataGrid should looks like this:

[image]

So how will I format Name and Age cells to textbox cell. Gender and State cell to Combobox cell?

Answer (score 1):

If you require more fields in the future, and want to reuse some of the functionality, take a look at the [WPF Property Grid](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid).

If your rows are fixed in this layout and you don't expect them to change frequently, you can consider an alternative approach using a standard grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock>Name</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">Age</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2">Gender</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3">State</TextBlock>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"></ComboBox>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"></ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the MVVM-Pattern then (I think so) you shoud create a ViewModel for cells and bind it as ItemSource. In your ViewModel you can set the Elements that you need. It should be possible to change between TextBoxes and ComboBoxes.

Possible you find here the answer:

[WPF DataGrid with different UserControl in each Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154839/wpf-datagrid-with-different-usercontrol-in-each-cell);

[WPF DataGrid different edit controls within a single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277874/wpf-datagrid-different-edit-controls-within-a-single-column)

http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector

P.S. Its not enough for an answer, but I have not enough Points to comment the question.